# How to solved datetime conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @dayscount int

SET @dayscount = CAST(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '21/02/2021', 103), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '22/02/2021',103)) AS int)

SELECT @dayscount
```

I get this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: As far as I know, d/m/y is not a valid SQL date format.  MySQL only supports valid ISO date formats like y/m/d.

Comment: @CharlesEF so how can i solved the problems. Please help the me. I want to used datediff function between two dates which are dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: If you store dates as DATE instead of varchar, you don't have these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the CONVERT function, the data type should be `date` type instead of `varchar` type.

```
select CAST(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, '21/02/2021', 103), CONVERT(date, '22/02/2021',103)) AS int)
```